# I drew a Ball from class and It's stuck in the same place (python3/pygame)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, pygame

I have a Ball class and I drew a ball from that class. No matter what coordinates I put the ball is either stuck in the low middle part of the window or dissapears completely

```
#windowsize is (1200, 600)

class Ball():

def __init__(self,x,y,radius,color):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.radius = radius
    self.color  = color

def Draw(self,screen):
    pygame.draw.circle(window,self.color,[self.x,self.x],self.radius)

ball   = Ball(600,300,8,red)

while loop:
    ball.Draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip
```

[screenshot](https://prnt.sc/wbnlvq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 typos:

The parentheses are missing after `pygame.display.flip`

<s>`pygame.display.flip`</s>

```py
pygame.display.flip()
```

The ball is drawn at `[self.x,self.x]` rather than `[self.x,self.y]`:

<s>`pygame.draw.circle(window,self.color,[self.x,self.x],self.radius)`</s>

```py
pygame.draw.circle(window,self.color, [self.x, self.y], self.radius)
```

Comment: thanks, I looked a lot of times at it and didn't see it